# create and fill a dataframe with dates as index and fill with arrys in pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, date

I would like to create a dataframe with dates as index and to fill the dataframe with two array. I try to make myself clear.

I have two array:

```
import numpy as np
qq = np.zeros(24)
hh = np.zeros(24)
```

They refer to each hour of a specific day. I would like to put the in a dataframe. This is what I have tried:

```
delta = pd.Timedelta("1 days")
start = '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
start_date = pd.to_datetime(start,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


df = pd.DataFrame([qq,hh] ,columns=['Qout','h'],
                  index=pd.date_range(start_date, periods=24, freq='H'))
```

This is my solution:

```
df['Qout'] = qq
df['h']    = hh
```

What do you think?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, this should give you the desired output. Keep in mind that i am transposing as the dataframe is created. I'm unsure what kind of error you were getting, but I got one where the array's were being read as columns and as such I transposed the dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
qq = np.zeros(24)
hh = np.zeros(24)
df = pd.DataFrame([qq,hh,pd.date_range(start_date, periods=24, freq='H')]).T
df.columns = ['Qout','h','Dates']
df = df.set_index('Dates')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want 0 in all of your DataFrame you can use this instead

```
start = '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
start_date = pd.to_datetime(start,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df = pd.DataFrame(0,index=pd.date_range(start_date, periods=24, freq='H'),columns = ['Qout','h'])
```